# A limit involving elliptic integral of first kind

Tags: limits

How to find

$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \dfrac{\int_{\cos^{-1}{(1/m)}}^{\pi/2} \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-m^2 \cos^2 t}}}{(m-\sqrt{m^2-1})}$$

Is it amenable to integration inside the integral sign?

Comment: But from the square root in the denominator we get $$1\geq m^2$$. How can $m$ tends to infinity?

Comment: Thanks, corrected  the typos

Comment: $$2{}{}{}{}{}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We rewrite the limit as:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\int_{\arccos x}^{\pi/2} \dfrac{x^2 dt}{\sqrt{x^2-\cos^2 t}}}{(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})}$$

Or:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\int_0^x \dfrac{x^2 dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Or:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2\int_0^1 \dfrac{ dz}{\sqrt{1-x^2 z^2}\sqrt{1-z^2}}}{(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})}$$

And now we can use the (much despised) L'Hospital rule.

First, the numerator:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(x^2\int_0^1 \frac{ dz}{\sqrt{1-x^2 z^2}\sqrt{1-z^2}}\right)=x \int_0^1 \frac{(2-x^2 z^2) dz}{(1-x^2 z^2)^{3/2}\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$

Now the denominator:

$$\frac{d}{dx} (1-\sqrt{1-x^2})=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

We get:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{1-x^2} \int_0^1 \frac{(2-x^2 z^2) dz}{(1-x^2 z^2)^{3/2}\sqrt{1-z^2}}=2\int_0^1 \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}= \pi$$

> Answer: $$\lim_{m\to\infty} \dfrac{\int_{\cos^{-1}{(1/m)}}^{\pi/2} \dfrac{  dt}{\sqrt{1-m^2 \cos^2 t}}}{(m-\sqrt{m^2-1})}=  \pi$$

Numerically this result is confirmed.

Comment: Thanks. Variable change and L.Hospital nicely combined.

Comment: Can I request you to remove the constant $2$ in my changed question? It is just getting carried through, so answer could be just $\pi$

Comment: @Narasimham, why did you put it there then? If you want, you can edit my answer yourself

Comment: OK, with your accordance.